# ESP8266 Webster very that passes data to serial

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Hello I am trying to get my ESP to run a webserver that will accept a string of text an output that text through a the uart serial pins to my arduino I can't find out how to do it I would apreshiate it

My seyup would be 
Arduino connected to the esp through serial pins the esp would start a server and my pc would open the webserver and type in a string of text that string would transmit to the arduino

Comment: The question seems quite unclear, perhaps adding what you tried could precise it

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'll put this in an answer :)

What I understand is you want a simple 'webserver' on your ESP, that listens to simple GET requests, takes the query string, and sends that over the serial line to your Arduino.

Firstly, are you capable of flashing new firmware to the ESP?
It's not hard, but as I understand your request, you will need to be able to do it.

Then you need to pick what would be your preferred approach:

- Flash NodeMcu firmware, and expand the webserver lua example to do what you want.
- Set up the Arduino IDE to work with the ESP (tutorials exist), and write a Arduino sketch to do what you want.
- You could also use esp-open-sdk, or the official Espressif SDK, and write what you want in C, but since you sound like a beginner, the two previous options are likley a better choice, their easier.

I expect the NodeMcu/lua way might be the quickest, although if you're already familiar with the Arduino IDE that might be a better choice.

If there are details you are stuck on, expand your question, and I'll see if I can stick them in the answer.